# how to add data one existing key memcache php?

Tags: php, memcached

I have a large amount of data in memcache, and currently i am troubling with How can i update value on memcache?

I have set value with multi-dimention array..

and now i have two cases here:

1. I want to add new value in Memcache in same key
2. I want to update some value of one particular array.

I know i can do that by `get -> modify -> set`

```
$data=$m->get('foo');

$data[]=array('id'=>134,'title'=>'My First Car','content'=>'I love my car');

$m->set('foo',$data,TRUE,0);
```

In this example..user can change its `title, content` etc. so i need to update these information in memcache.

But getting data on every change which is more than 1MB, that will not be a good idea.

and I also learn about `append` but [**it says**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/memcached.append.php) it only works for `string` values. that means i can not append `Array` to with existing `key`.

Is there any way to set/update data on existing key without getting data?

Please help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just call $m->get the first time to populate $data, and don't call it again if you're just making updates:-

```
if (!count($data))
    $data=$m->get('foo');

$data[]=array('id'=>134,'title'=>'My First Car','content'=>'I love my car');

$m->set('foo',$data,TRUE,0);
```

If you make $data global then you can reference it from other functions

Comment: thanks @joep1978.. i will try with global variable. but is there not any other way without calling `$m->get`?

Comment: No, $m->get has to be called at least once or you will set foo to be an array containing just the most recent append